# Getting Json fetched data on second attempt

Tags: javascript, json, fetch, state, auth0

**I am getting my fetched Json data on second attempt. I have to refresh my screen two times to get the data. Thoughts?**

```
var data = [];
    class Profiel extends Component {
      constructor(props) {

      }


      componentDidMount() {
      this.setState({fetching:true},()=>{
        this.getData().then(JsonData => data=JsonData).then(console.log(data));
      });

      }
      getData(){
        return fetch('https://Domain.eu.auth0.com/userinfo', {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
          },
        }).then((response) => {return response.json()})
      };
```

Comment: Why do you have to refresh your App two times?

Comment: Please indent properly so we can better understand the code.

Comment: Either your component is not mounting on the first page load (where's the HTML?), or your token is not in place until _after_ the first page load (more likely).

Comment: This is my user profile screen on my react native app. When I click on  my profile button, I jump to this screen. but on first attempt  my profile page is empty plus  data variable is also undefined in console. But when I go back to main screen and then click back on profile button, I can see my profile.... I use hard coded token for now, so token shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: My Html looks like this.
render() {
return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
            <Image style={styles.avatar}
              source={{ uri: data.picture }} />
            <Text style={styles.name}>{data.email} </Text>
          </View>
}